# Customizing one android source code as two apps

Tags: android, firebase

I have an android source code which I want to customized as two applications. So, I created two folders with the same code and different project names. With one google account, I have created two firebase projects. The difference between two apps are:

1- Using two `google-services.json` from the firebase account.

2- `app\src\main\assets\config.json` where there is a `home_url`. I provided two URLs since each app connects to its own website.

3- `app\res\mipmap` where there are some icons for each of them.

I also have created to keys with `keytool`. Finally I have run "create signed APK" in each project.

On the phone side, the first app is installed without any problem. However, when I want to install the second, it gives me the following error

> App not installed.
>   The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you add a different package name in the build.gradle files of each app? And also in the manifest?

Comment: You should be building your two apps with different "flavors" as configured in build.gradle.  You can give each app a different package name that way.

Comment: I have to say that `applicationId` for both are the same! and that is actually the source code provider

Comment: Well, I deleted the firebase app in the project and created another android app with a new package name. Then in the source code, I use that string as `applicationId`. After building the signed apk, still I get the same error. How can I analyze the apk file to view its package name. Maybe something was wrong during the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change package name of one app like **com.xxx**

- First change the directory (folder) name in project structure.
- Also change package name in android manifest file.
- At last change the package name in gradle file

Comment: I did that but still something is wrong because I get the same error. How can I check the installer log inside the phone?

Comment: Why you want to check installer log

Answer (score 0):

This is a package name conflict issue. you are encountering this because you are using the same package name in both the apps.

Try to create with a unique package names in the apps as well as in the firebase console which will resolve your issue.